# How to run a Strapi JS API in IIS with iisnode?

Tags: iis-8.5, iisnode, strapi

I'm trying to run a Strapi JS REST API ([strapi.io](https://strapi.io)) in IIS 8.5 using iisnode. But I keep running into HTTP status 500 errors like below.

- The `IIS_IUSRS` group has write permissions on the directory (required by iisnode);
- I use a dotenv (.env) file to specify the `production` environment variables;
- When I run it standalone on the server by executing `node server.js` it works fine. But not when I run it via the IIS web application.

Does anyone have some tips to get this working? Any known caveats?

```
iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.
HRESULT: 0x2
HTTP status: 500
HTTP subStatus: 1002
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error

You are receiving this HTTP 200 response because system.webServer/iisnode/@devErrorsEnabled configuration setting is 'true'.

In addition to the log of stdout and stderr of the node.exe process, consider using debugging and ETW traces to further diagnose the problem.

The last 64k of the output generated by the node.exe process to stderr is shown below:
(node:4792) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.
(node:4792) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
```

Comment: Do you have found a solution to this problem? I have the same error

Comment: Saeid, I didn't get it to work. I tried everything mentioned below, but still no luck. I moved to a Digital Ocean Ubuntu droplet.

Answer (score 2):

In your strapi project folder go to below paths and update.

> config\environments\production\server.json

```
{
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": "${process.env.PORT || 8081}",
  "proxy": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "autoReload": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "cron": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "admin": {
    "autoOpen": false
  }
}
```

> web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="yourappname">
          <match url="/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <iisnode
      node_env="production"
      debuggingEnabled="true"
      nodeProcessCommandLine="&quot;%programfiles%\nodejs\node.exe&quot;" 
      interceptor="&quot;%programfiles%\iisnode\interceptor.js&quot;" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Still not working. What node version do you use? Are there any other changes to folder security or something required?

Comment: Node **v10.15.0**, Npm **6.4.1**
The folder must have "IIS_User" permission to read and write.
Maybe you can run "SET NODE_ENV=production" on cmd.